# MDX query returns different values when executed using openrowset

Tags: sql, mdx, olap-cube

When I execute the same MDX query on the analytic server where the cube itself is stored and via an openrowset function call from a sql server, I get notably different output.

```
--MDX query--
```

[image: MDX executed on analytic server]

```
@sql =  '--MDX query--'   
exec(N'select * from openrowset
             (''MSOLAP''
             , ''Data Source= ANALYTIC SERVER; Catalog= CATALOG;''
             ,''' + @sql + ''');'
```

[image: MDX executed via SQL]

Is there any way to get the same output on the SQL side as when querying the analytic server directly?

I'm doing something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504728/sql-query-cubes/504763#504763), the solution for which was suggested to be using openquery and / or openrowset.

Other questions have noted the issue when using [openrowset](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/52053/mdx-vs-mdx-msolap-openrowset.html) and hierarchical MDX queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the issue comes from using hierarchical calls in MDX, which leads to the returned values being different when using openrowset.

The solution I found that was very simply to use the [OLAPextensions add on](https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/) instead, as suggested by a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984223/how-can-i-pull-data-from-an-mdx-olap-cube-into-a-standard-sql-server-table)  . This solution was much faster and easier to get working on a local server than setting up a linked server for openquery. The table it returns is exactly the same as that from the analytic server.

```
DECLARE @Server NVARCHAR(30) = 'ANALYTIC SERVER'
DECLARE @Database NVARCHAR(50) = 'CATALOG';

DECLARE @MDX NVARCHAR(MAX) = '--MDX query--'

EXEC ExecuteOLAP @Server, @Database, @MDX;
```

[image]

Comment: it is a very night clr solution: we use this stored procedure and have not used OPENQUERY since installing it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the same output...

```
@sql =  '--MDX query--'   
exec(N'select "[Blah].[Blah 3].[Blah 3].[Table Code Level 2]" from openrowset
             (''MSOLAP''
             , ''Data Source= ANALYTIC SERVER; Catalog= CATALOG;''
             ,''' + @sql + ''');'
```

Comment: I'm not so much giving out about the extra columns, more the content of them is completely different or unusable in many cases. I'm trying understand how I can get openrowset to return exactly the same set of columns and values. Even in this case NST.02 is returned instead of the correct NST.02.06

Comment: @HenryE Can you add the MDX to your question?

Comment: I managed to install an extension that returns the values more accurately and thankfully also doesn't require using a linked server